# generate list separate input character

Tags: r, dataframe, split

I have a table with a column name HS where data is like this:

```
HS <- c("44.01 44.12","44.1234","4561.10 4562.10 4620.1")
```

I would like to get a list :

```
listcodes = c("44.01","44.12","44.1234","4561.10","4562.10","4620.1")
```

---

## Question Update

What if I have this dataset

```
HS       PROD
44.10 44.12  AA
44.13        BB
```

and that I want to repeat the HS2017 codes for every prod codes like

```
HS     PROD
44.10   AA
44.12   AA
44.13   BB
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `strsplit` and `unlist`

```
> unlist(strsplit(HS, " "))
[1] "44.01"   "44.12"   "44.1234" "4561.10" "4562.10" "4620.1"
```

Answer (score 2):

We may use `scan` or `strsplit`

```
scan(text = paste(HS, collapse = " "), what = numeric(), quiet = TRUE)
```

If it should be `character`

```
scan(text = paste(HS, collapse = " "), what = "", quiet = TRUE)
[1] "44.01"   "44.12"   "44.1234" "4561.10" "4562.10" "4620.1"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `separte_rows`

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  separate_rows(HS) %>%
  type.convert(as.is = TRUE)
```

which gives

```
# A tibble: 3 × 2
     HS PROD 
  <dbl> <chr>
1  44.1 AA
2  44.1 AA
3  44.1 BB
```

or just

```
> df %>%  separate_rows(HS)
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  HS    PROD 
  <chr> <chr>
1 44.10 AA
2 44.12 AA
3 44.13 BB
```

Answer (score 0):

separate_rows(df, y, z, convert = TRUE) works fine
for the second part of my question